# 'of a kind prescribed'

Tags: meaning-in-context

> In civil cases, in the Queen’s Bench Division, there is a right to a jury under section 69 of the
>   Supreme Court Act 1981 if:
>   ...
>   3. any question or issue **of a kind prescribed** is raised [but none has yet been so
>   prescribed].

Would someone please explain clause 3? I tried substituting [of a kind](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/of-a-kind?q=of+a+kind) but I still don't perceive it.
Also, what's the meaning of [prescribed](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/prescribe?q=prescribe) here? What's being prescribed?
I guess that 'raised' is the verb for 'any question or issue'?

Source: P153, How the Law Works, Gary Slapper

Answer (score 1):

A question or issue “of a kind prescribed” refers to one that meets some previously stated criteria.  To *prescribe* is, here, to specify a rule or guide  ([Wiktionary's](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prescribe#Verb) sense 2).

The quotation says that if a question or issue is raised that falls into a certain class, then there is a right to a jury trial.

Comment: Thank you. To clarify, is 'kind prescribed' reversed here, an anastrophe? Should it be interpreted as 'of a prescribed kind'? Will you please to respond in your answer, and not as a comment?